# unable to create postgis extension ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis, psql, postgresql-9.3

When I try run this command

```
sudo -u postgres psql -h localhost -d template_postgis -f /Users/MyUser/postgis-2.0.6/postgis/postgis.sql
```

I get this error

```
SET
BEGIN
psql:/Users/MyUser/postgis-2.0.6/postgis/postgis.sql:49: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory
psql:/Users/MyUser/postgis-2.0.6/postgis/postgis.sql:54: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
.
.
.
psql:/Users/MyUser/postgis-2.0.6/postgis/postgis.sql:6034: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/Users/MyUser/postgis-2.0.6/postgis/postgis.sql:6040: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK
```

I am using postgresql 9.1 with rails 4 on mac osx. I need to get this fixed to run migration files successfully. Any help will really be very thankful.

Comment: Could be that you don't have postgis installed. What does `select * from pg_available_extensions;` say ? [either that or you failed to run ldconfig] Does the postgis-2.0.so actually exist?

Comment: name              | adminpack
default_version   | 1.0
installed_version | 1.0
comment           | administrative functions for PostgreSQL
name              | autoinc
default_version   | 1.0
installed_version | 
comment           | functions for autoincrementing fields
name              | btree_gin
default_version   | 1.0
installed_version | 

total 8 records but nth saying postgis but i have postgis installed in it

Comment: 1) locate the library 2) see if its location matches $libdir. 3) try to rerun ldconfig

Comment: @joop
In mac osx it gives me error sudo: ldconfig: command not found
so i found this as alternative for mac osx.
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache
it did not through any error

Comment: I don't know about OSX's dyn loader. The symptoms suggest that the postgis .so library is not present, or located at the wrong place. (the postgis.sql refers to binary objects within the library, and basically announces their presence to the catalogs) So your postgis is either not installed, or installed wrong.