# sudo -u postgres not working in mac os x

Tags: macos, postgresql, shell, command-line, sudo

I have recently installed postgresql 9.1 after uninstalling postgres 9.3 as per the requirement of my project but I am not able to run basic sudo command with postgres user.

```
sudo -u postgres -h localhost createdb template_postgis
```

This gives me no error but shows the usage of sudo:

```
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u
        user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
        name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
        name|#uid] file ...
```

Though sudo works for other projects and commands but not in this. It was working earlier perfectly. I will be really thankful if someone helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the manual page for `sudo` (which you can view by running `man sudo` in the terminal), you can see that this is exactly what the `-h` option does:

```
   -h          The -h (help) option causes sudo to print a usage message and exit.
```

You should be able to run the command without that option:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb template_postgis
```

Comment: The `-h <hostname>` argument should be given after the `createdb` part of the command as it should be an argument to `createdb` and not to `sudo`.

Comment: do u guys have any idea why i am still getting this error after this working fine.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560707/unable-to-create-postgis-extension-error-could-not-access-file-libdir-postgis